# How to restrict web service data contract properties based on user role

Tags: web-services, soa, user-roles

I have the following web service:

```
[DataContract]
public class Project
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[OperationContract]
public Project GetProject(long Id);
```

Now I want to add a `SecretData` property that should only be exposed to certain users.  I've come up with several ideas, but none of them sit quite well with me:

1. Add a nullable `SecretData` property to `Project`.  If the user doesn't have permission to view it, set it to `null`.  This seems like the simplest approach, but how would a consumer tell the difference between a "no permission" `null` and a legitimate `null` value?
2. Solution 1, but also add a boolean `CanViewSecretData` property.  This addresses the legitimate `null` problem, but seems cumbersome.
3. Provide a separate operation `SecretDataType GetSecretData(long projectId)` to retrieve the secret data, and return an error if the user does not have permission to call it.  This keeps the data contract clean, but I see us ending up with lots of separate operations that need to be called in order to construct a full object.

Is there a better approach out there?

Answer (score 2):

I've got no idea what framework you are using, but from a general web services perspective here is what I suggest. In the XSD for `Project`, add an optional `SecretData` element to `Project`. When the user is not permitted to read `SecretData`, do not include the element in the response. Otherwise, include the element and when `SecretData` is `null` set the `xsi:nil` attribute to `true`.